# Get the same div class text into array, using array to get the name

Tags: arrays, prototype

I am trying to get the name of the same class div into array and access each name using array.prototype. I can use $('.class-name').each but I'd like to re-use existing code which already uses array.prototype.

In html,

```
<div class="file">file-1</div>
<div class="file">file-2</div>
```

In JQuery,

```
var files = $('.file').text();
Array.prototype.forEach.call(files, function(e) {
 alert(e);
});
```

The e in each call is a letter such as 'f', 'i', 'l', 'e', '-', '1', instead of the name 'file-1'. It is the same in 'file-2'.

How can I change it to the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. The problem is the use of .text() at line #1;

```
var files = $('.file');
files.each(function() {
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```js
$('.file').each(function(){
   alert($(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="file">file-1</div>
<div class="file">file-2</div>
```